# How to repoint supervisor 4.0.4 from python2 to python3?

Tags: python-3.x, supervisord

I have a python 2.7 4.0.4 install of supervisor.
Python3 is also installed on the box and want to move supervisor to using python3.
instead of python2.

My guess is to stop on 2... uninstall.... install using pip3 and then restart using existing .conf files for the services...

be nice to minimize downtime so any other suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move Supervisor from Python 2 to Python 3, here are the steps you can follow to minimize downtime:

1. Stop all running Supervisor services.
2. Uninstall Supervisor Python 2.7 using pip.
3. Install Superrvisor using pip3 for Python 3.
4. Check and adjust the executable paths for Python in your .conf configuration files to point to Python 3.
5. Restart Supervisor and verify that everything is working correctly with Python 3

By following these steps, you should be able to migrate Supervisor to Python 3 while minimizing downtime.

Comment: Thanks for this... I'm using virtual environments for all running processes so I shouldn't have to repoint all the conf files...